# Making animation run after transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scale

How can I make the bounce animation run after the object finishes scaling so it appears to all be fluid? The animation delay property doesn't seem to match up with the transition delay prop. Thanks for any help.

```js
        function myFunction() {
            var image = document.getElementById('test');
            image.style.WebkitTransform = ('scale(2,2)');
            var piss = document.getElementById('piss');
            piss.classList.remove('bounce');
            piss.offsetWidth = piss.offsetWidth;
            piss.classList.add('bounce') ;
        }
```

```css
    div#test  {
        position:relative;
        display: block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
        margin: 50px auto;
        transition-duration: 1.5s
        
    }
            
    .bounce {
        animation: bounce 450ms;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
            


@keyframes bounce{
  25%{transform: scale(1.15);}
  50%{transform: scale(0.9);}
  75%{transform: scale(1.1);}
  100%{transform: scale(1.0);}
}
```

```html
<div id='piss'>
<div id='test'> </div> 
    </div>

<button class = 'butt' onclick = 'myFunction()'>FIRST</button>
```

Comment: why you keep repeating the same question again : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263252/using-bounce-animation-on-a-scaled-element / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54281912/bounce-animation-on-a-scaled-object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second time value in the `animation` shorthand CSS property sets the `animation-delay` value:

```
animation: bounce 450ms 1.5s;
```

waits until scaling has finished.

(The first time value of 450ms is used  for the `animation-duration` value.)